# Bootstrap Grid Column Height 100%

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, height

I'm using bootstrap grid system to make some nested grids. The only problem is I cant get the grid to span the whole screen, currently its just 1 line tall.

Is there any way to make it fill 100% of the parent container? I've tried simple stuff like css height attributes.

this is my code below

```
    <div class="container">
<div class="row" style="height:100vh">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="height:100%">
        <div class="row" style="height:50%">
            <div class="col-md-6">2</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="height:50%">
            <div class="col-md-6">4</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="height:100%">
        1
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Found a solution. Using height:100vh on the primary row, it spreads the div to the whole page and then using normal percentages within the row scales the other divs relatively.

Answer (score 2):

You could add `height:100%` to each `.col-md-6`.

See here: http://codepen.io/Nazzanuk/pen/yNLNBd

Comment: This will break the responsive grid when resizing the window

Answer (score 0):

For the div to expand fully, `div .col-md-6 { height:100%; position:relative; }` should work. Can we see your CSS?

Comment: display relative ?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS viewport units:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

This is magic!